# Почему не работает условие if?

Tags: php

Почему не работает условие? Разве переменные нельзя складывать? (phpstorm ругается)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. <del>Слаживать</del> складывать 2. В `if` неправильное условие

Comment: @Евгений потому что потому что вы складываете строковые переменные, а не числовые. Запишите присвоение без апострофов: $a = 20; $b = 10; И ещё у вас в условии ошибка - оператор сравнения записывается так: == (два знака равно)

Comment: @Эдуард Точно, спасибо)

Comment: Не выкладывайте код картинками. Выкладывайте **текстом**!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хорошо

Comment: @Эдуард Насчет сложения я не очень понял. Например `var_dump('10' + '20');` вполне логично выводит `int(30)`. PHP не стесняется приводить операнды к числам (иногда даже там где это вообще не нужно). Или "шторму" такая вольность не нравится?

Comment: @tutankhamun а? что?) я не я и хата не моя)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Блин. Не тому собеседнику отправил :)

Comment: @tutankhamun `Или "шторму" такая вольность не нравится?` - именно так.

Answer (score 2):

Вы в **if** написали не сравнение `==` а присвоение `=`.

```
if($operators == '+')
```

Comment: автору уже сообщили об этом в первом комментарии

Comment: @Эдуард, уже вижу. Посмотрел просто что ответов нет.

Comment: @Abmin потому что такие вопросы закрываются как "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой" и ответа в них смысла нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, буду теперь знать. Мне ответ удалить?

Comment: Да оставь, может кто плюсанёт)